# Mutliple lines in title for UIAlertView

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uialertview

I want to put 2 lines in the title of UIAlertView with first line in bold and bigger font and second line with regular and smaller font.

Is there a direct way of doing it or do I need to extend the UIAlertView to write my own custom alert view. Any pointers.

Comment: I don't think there is a way to do it without writing your own. Take a look at this maybe https://www.cocoacontrols.com/controls/cnppopupcontroller

Answer (score 0):

UIAlertview has a title property and a body property.  The body property is a non bold and I think smaller font than the title property.  You could use the body as your smaller title property unless you need two titles and a body, in that case, you will have to roll your own.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I konw,before ios 7,you can write two UILabel,one text bold and one not.

Then add these subviews to UIAlertview.

Now,I think the only way is to define your own UIAlertView.It is easy.